# Segmentation fault using strcat using a single character

Tags: c, strcat

Here is my code:

```
int min = 0, i, z;
char star[18][100] = {0};
int temp = 0;
char TheStar[2];
TheStar[0] = '*';
TheStar[1] = '\0';


for(i = 0; i < 17; i++){
    if(min == 0 && PerHundredThousand > 0)
     min = PerHundredThousand[i];
    if(PerHundredThousand[i] < min)
     min = PerHundredThousand[i];}


for(z = 0; z < 17; z--){
     if(PerHundredThousand[z] > 0)
      temp = PerHundredThousand[z] / min;
     while(temp > 0){
         strcat(star[z], TheStar);
         temp = temp - 1;}
```

}

As you can see i'm trying to use strcat to add a '*' as long as temp is higher than 0 but I get a segmentation fault on:

```
strcat(star[z], TheStar);
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `PerHundredThousand > 0` looks suspicious, too.

Answer (score 3):

The second loop appears wrong:

```
for(z = 0; z < 17; z--){
```

Should probably be:

```
for(z = 0; z < 17; z++){
```

Otherwise it would loop a lot more times than intended (as well as write to invalid array positions).

Comment: Thanks my desk almost broke seeing that.

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop there is a mistake

```
if(min == 0 && PerHundredThousand > 0)
```

should be

```
if(min == 0 && PerHundredThousand[i] > 0)
```